Android apps like telegram and signal create duplicate contacts
Suppose I create a contact named "Miachel". This personal also exist on Telegram or Signal.
Later, I visited https://contacts.google.com/ and renamed it to "Michelle".
What happens is there are 2 copies of this contact in Contacts app in my phone now.
Michelle as google contact and Michael as "read-only telegram contact".
Sometime apps like whatsapp get confuse and show me contact with old name.
How do I avoid this?

Similar problem. If I deleted Michael in https://contacts.google.com/, Michael is still visible in Contacts app in my phone as "read-only telegram contact"
